# why my google cloud instance often shut down automatically by itself

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

my google cloud instance(compute engine) was shut down automatically with unknown reason

there is the event log for the instance

```
{"shutdownEvent":{},"bootCounter":"6","@type":"type.googleapis.com/cloud_integrity.IntegrityEvent"}

{
 insertId:  "0"  
 jsonPayload: {
  @type:  "type.googleapis.com/cloud_integrity.IntegrityEvent"   
  bootCounter:  "6"   
  shutdownEvent: {
  }
 }
 logName:  "projects/<xxxx>/logs/compute.googleapis.com%2Fshielded_vm_integrity"  
 receiveTimestamp:  "2019-05-09T10:14:29.112673979Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {
   instance_id:  "<xxxx>"    
   project_id:  "<xxxx>"    
   zone:  "us-west1-b"    
  }
  type:  "gce_instance"   
 }
 severity:  "NOTICE"  
 timestamp:  "2019-05-09T10:14:26.928978844Z"  
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
gcloud compute instances update INSTANCE_NAME --shielded-learn-integrity-policy
```

Instance must be running and have Integrity Monitoring enabled.

I don't know if this is secure though. Read more:

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/integrity-monitoring#updating-baseline

Comment: This issue occurs commonly after updating the machine's kernel. The Titan security chip that Google uses on most of its hardware finds that the Kernel is now different to the last baseline taken, and locks up the machine to protect it from any outside threats. The above command will resolve this by resetting that baseline to match your machines current/new setup, and should keep the security chip happy, as it's now operating as expected. :)

Comment: @Jack_Hu is there a way to disable this update.. its quite frustrating to see the server restarting

Comment: The kernel update? Sure. Don't use `sudo update && sudo upgrade`, or stop it from updating the `linux-kernel-*` packages. Don't do it though. Those updates are important. Just remember to update the baseline with the above command, after you've updating the kernel.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a [shielded VM](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/security-in-plaintext-use-shielded-vms-to-harden-your-gcp-workloads) with "integrity monitoring" enabled

... and most likely this is caused by an [integrity validation failure](https://cloud.google.com/security/shielded-cloud/automating-responses-integrity-failures).

Answer (score 1):

You might use [Stackdriver Advanced Logs Filters](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/advanced-filters) and try to get more details about the reason behind the shutdown, for example, sometimes instances are migrated ([Live Migration](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/live-migration)) and cause the behavior reported.

Some filters that may help you to determine what caused the shutdown on instances are:

1. Checking for migrations, in Stackdriver Advanced Logging filter, use following entries:

compute.instances.migrationOnHostMaintenance 
OR
compute.instances.migrateOnHostMaintenance

2. For [hostError](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/faq#hosterror), you can use following filter:

"compute.instances.hostError"

3. For VM Instance Stop:

resource.type="gce_instance"
protoPayload.methodName="v1.compute.instances.stop"

Answer (score 0):

had the some problem and confirmed from gcp that my vm had moved from one physics host to another..

pls feel free to open case and google customer support will help you diagnostics